# Passing a ref parameter to interop

Tags: c#, interop, com-interop, unmanaged

I'm trying to call that function from within c# but i'm currently stuck in this exception: *System.ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'*

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
[DispId(100)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
object GetTextValue([In] int nSamples, [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref object afData);
```

this is what I tried to do which is obviously not working:

```
object values = new object[] { };
atlasParameter.GetTextValue (0, ref values);
```

Not sure how to find this, as this is the only documentation I have:

[image: GetTextValue]

Thanks

Comment: Why are you asking for 0 samples?

Comment: Is it `GetTextValue` or `GetValueText`?

Comment: @mjwills It fails with a valid sample which I can get from calling another function. It's the array type I can't get hold off and I updated the name, thanks for spotting it.

Comment: Based on documentation, the interface definition may be incorrect. You should clarify what kind of data type array the parameters and results are, and review the interface definition with reference to this page. [Default Marshaling for Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-arrays)